# how to get arcgis IdentyfyTask addCallback `s value?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

i was tested to the IdentyfyTask.

But I could not get a response before the value addCallback.

i want to the pnu values.

But pnu vaule was alwayes undefined...

my code is follows.

```
function poiClick(){
    agmap.addEvent("click", function(evt){

         getPoi=     krcgis.Function.PoiClick(agmap ,evt);

         console.log("X === ",getPoi.x);
         console.log("Y === ",getPoi.y);
         console.log("PNU === ",getPoi.pnu);
    });
}

 PoiClick : function(map, evt) {
         poiInfo = {};
         poiInfo.x =evt.mapPoint.x;
         poiInfo.y =evt.mapPoint.y;
         var targetLayerId = 'LP_PA_CBND'; 
        var url = map.Layers.getLayerInfo(targetLayerId).SVC_URL;
        var map = map.getMap();
        //파라미터 설정.
        var idParams = new krcgis.core.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
        idParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
        idParams.mapExtent = map.extent;
        idParams.returnGeometry = true;
        idParams.tolerance = 0;
        idParams.layerOption = krcgis.core.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
        idParams.width = map.width;
        idParams.height = map.height;


        idTask = new krcgis.core.tasks.IdentyfyTask(url);
        idTask
        .execute(idParams)
        .addCallback(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                poiInfo.pnu =response[0].value;
            }
        });
        return poiInfo;
    }
```

The results were as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IdentifyTask returns a IdentifyResult object. so you code *response[0].value* will be undefined.
you should use something like ***response[0].feature.attributes.PNU***

Comment: But look out from the Chrome developer tools console can check the value pnu